# Weak Law of Large Numbers for uniformly integrable, independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

On page 58-59 of the notes by Knill (found here :http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math144_1994/probability.pdf ) there is a version of the WLLN whose proof I have trouble understand.

On page 59, I don't understand how we go from
$$ ||S_n||_1 \le ||S_n^{(R)}||_1+ ||T_n^{(R)}||_1 $$

to

$$\le ||S_n^{(R)}||_2 + 2 \sup_{1\le l \le n } E[|X_l| : |X_l| \ge R] $$

I know I am supposed to use the Minkowski and Cauchy-Schwarz inequalities but I can't work out the details. Please show me how.

Answer (score 0):

The bound $\lVert S_n^{(R)}\rVert_1 \leqslant \lVert S_n^{(R)}\rVert_2$ is indeed a consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

For the second term, notice that 
$$T_n^{(R)}=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\mathbf 1\{|X_i|\gt R\}-\mathbb E\left[X_i\mathbf 1\{|X_i|\gt R\}\right],$$
hence taking the $L^1$-norm, 
$$\lVert T_n^{(R)}\rVert_1\leqslant \frac 2n\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb E\left|X_i\mathbf 1\{|X_i|\gt R\}\right|.$$
Since for each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, we have 
$$\mathbb E\left|X_i\mathbf 1\{|X_i|\gt R\}\right|\leqslant \max_{1\leqslant l\leqslant n}\mathbb E\left[|X_l|\mathbf 1\{|X_l|\gt R\} \right],$$ 
we get the wanted inequality.

Comment: How did you get that $Y_i =X_i-X_i^{(R)}= X_i 1\{|X_i| >R \} -E[X_i 1\{ |X_i| >R \} $

Comment: Never mind , I got it. You use the fact that $E[X_n]=0$.